# JPA/hibernate subquery in from clause

Tags: hibernate, jpa, subquery

We're using JPA with hibernate as the provider,
we have a query that contains a join with a subquery in the FROM clause, but we get the following error:

> org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: ( near
>   line 1, column 75 [SELECT sd FROM
>   com.hp.amber.datamodel.entities.analysis.SnapshotDates sd, (SELECT
>   max(x.changeDate) maxChangeDate, x.viewId, x.state FROM
>   com.hp.amber.datamodel.entities.analysis.SnapshotDates x WHERE
>   x.changeDate<:date AND x.viewId in (:viewIds) AND x.state=:state GROUP
>   BY x.viewId, x.state) sd2 WHERE sd.viewId = sd2.viewId AND sd.state =
>   :state AND sd.changeDate = sd2.maxChangeDate]

This is the query:

```
SELECT sd 
FROM SnapshotDates sd, 
     (SELECT max(x.changeDate) maxChangeDate, x.viewId, x.state 
      FROM SnapshotDates x
     WHERE x.changeDate<:date AND x.viewId in (:viewIds) AND x.state=:state
GROUP BY x.viewId, x.state) sd2
WHERE sd.viewId = sd2.viewId 
      AND sd.state = :state 
      AND sd.changeDate = sd2.maxChangeDate
```

Thank you for helping

Comment: jpa does not support subquery in 'FROM' and "SELECT' clauses, you have to change your query and put subquery in the 'WHERE' clause.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

**Update for Hibernate >= 6.1**

This is possible as of [Hibernate 6.1 (released June 14th 2022)](https://in.relation.to/2022/06/14/orm-61-final/):

> Long requested support for subqueries (including lateral subqueries) in the from-clause of HQL and Criteria queries

See example code from a unit test file in the Hibernate repository [`HQLTest.java`](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/d475b597151e3e0d224f8e0c97b1645802627228/hibernate-core/src/test/java/org/hibernate/orm/test/hql/HQLTest.java#L3108):

```
    @Test
    public void test_hql_derived_root_example() {
        doInJPA(this::entityManagerFactory, entityManager -> {
            //tag::hql-derived-root-example[]
            List<Tuple> calls = entityManager.createQuery(
                "select d.owner, d.payed " +
                "from (" +
                "  select p.person as owner, c.payment is not null as payed " +
                "  from Call c " +
                "  join c.phone p " +
                "  where p.number = :phoneNumber) d",
                Tuple.class)
            .setParameter("phoneNumber", "123-456-7890")
            .getResultList();
            //end::hql-derived-root-example[]
        });
    }
```

**Older Versions of Hibernate:**

I did not think HQL could do subqueries in the from clause

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch16.html#queryhql-subqueries

note the sentence:

> Note that HQL subqueries can occur only in the select or where clauses.

I imagine you could change it to a native query and execute it that way.

Answer (score 4):

Your SQL is:

> SELECT sd  FROM SnapshotDates sd, 
>        (SELECT max(x.changeDate) maxChangeDate, x.viewId, x.state 
>         FROM SnapshotDates x
>        WHERE x.changeDate<:date AND x.viewId in (:viewIds) AND
>   x.state=:state GROUP BY x.viewId, x.state) sd2 WHERE sd.viewId =
>   sd2.viewId 
>         AND sd.state = :state 
>         AND sd.changeDate = sd2.maxChangeDate

You can rewrite your sql like

```
SELECT sd 
FROM SnapshotDates sd, 
WHERE sd.viewId in (:viewIds)
    AND sd.state = :state
    sd.changeDate = (SELECT max(x.changeDate) FROM SnapshotDates x WHERE x.viewId = ds.viewId AND x.state = ds.state)
```

Find inspired by example

```
SELECT m FROM Professor m WHERE (SELECT COUNT(e) FROM Professor e WHERE e.manager = m) > 0
```

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/JPA/EJBQLWhereClauseWithSubQuery.htm

My similar example
I had SQL

```
select k.* from kredits k, 
  (select client_id, max(r_date) r_date from kredits k group by client_id) k2 
where k.client_id = k2.client_id 
    AND k.r_date = k2.r_date 
order by k.id
```

Rewrite it for PQL

```
select k From Kredit k
where k.rDate = (select MAX(k2.rDate) from Kredit k2 where k2.clientId = k.clientId)
order by k.id
```

It will be translated to

```
select kredit0_.id as id28_, kredit0_.client_id as client59_28_ from kredits kredit0_ 
where kredit0_.r_date=(select MAX(kredit1_.r_date) from kredits kredit1_ where kredit1_.client_id=kredit0_.client_id) 
order by kredit0_.id
```

return same result as SQL.

Use Hebirnate 3.3.1 with MySQL 5.0.24

Comment: Please help me in translation of query: `select t.order_state,t.claim_number,t.id from (select * from t_repair_order where claim_number='SERCON201465') t
where t.order_state = 'Cancel'
  and not exists (
  select 1 from (select * from t_repair_order where claim_number='SERCON201465') tt
  where tt.id > t.id and tt.order_state <> t.order_state
);`

Answer (score 4):

Subqueries (including lateral subqueries) in the from-clause of HQL and Criteria queries are supported from Hibernate 6.1 Final

https://in.relation.to/2022/06/14/orm-61-final/