# JPA Count * of Group By result

Tags: java, mysql, spring-mvc, jpa-2.0, jpql

I have the following SQL query:

```sql
select count(*) from (
    select *, count(*)  
    from po_item 
    where sku_code ="SKU_TEST_4" and allocated = false and wip = false 
    group by warehouse
) as t
```

I was able to write the following inner query with Criteria API and JPQL

```sql
select *, count(*)
from po_item 
where sku_code ="SKU_TEST_4" and allocated = false and wip = false
group by warehouse
```

but couldn't write it along with the outer part. How to do it with JPQL or Criteria API?

Comment: Could you post the queries you have tried and expected and actual outputs. Probability it helps others to understand and arrive to answer easier

Comment: My requirement is pretty simple. How to do query "select count(*) from (select *, count(*)  from po_item where sku_code ="SKU_TEST_4" and allocated = false and wip = false group by warehouse) as t" using JPA Criteria or JPQL

Comment: You cannot create subqueries in `FROM` clause with JPQL: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7291855/2387977

Comment: I think then I got ****ed with JPQL...because my entire project is running with JPQL.....What is the best alternative to do this other than using native queries