# how i can manipulate nested query j2ee hibernate

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa, jakarta-ee, hql

I have the following query, the problem that hibernate does not support nested after the 'from' I tried to create a view, but it did not work, I want to know how can I use hibernate to run this query correctly

```
SELECT sum(dc.nbrDefaut) def, a.nb control,c.id_of
FROM controlequalite c ,detailscontrole dc,
(select sum(nbreControlle) nb, id_monitrice 
  from controlequalite group by id_monitrice) a
  where c.id = dc.id_controle 
and c.id_monitrice = a.id_monitrice 
and  c.date >= '2016-03-25 00:00:00' 
group by c.id_monitrice,c.id_of;
```

Comment: So could you give us more exception information?

Comment: the query that I created above works well in mysql but the problem is that when I tried to execute with HQL I found that did not supporet the nested query
I thought to create a view, but it does not work

Comment: Create a view of subquery?

Comment: yes create a view with subquery

Comment: Take a look of this [JPA/hibernate subquery in from clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7269010/jpa-hibernate-subquery-in-from-clause) which said HQL do not support feature you want.

Answer (score 0):

With a query like this, the simplest way is to use a native query. I'm assuming you are using JPA/Hibernate as ORM, so you can simply do like:

```
List<YourObject> resultList = yourEntityManager.createNativeQuery("nativeSQLhere", YourObject.class).getResultList();
```

Comment: I didn't use native query before can you help me to understand more about it